# I want to be able to delete or edit users already in my database with PHP

Tags: php, database

I am trying to view current users with the eventual option of deleting and editing a user. 
$dbc is in another file in my header.html file. 
The only output I receive that doesn't include the header/footer is:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kyle_Site\Programming Rite\controle\view_users.php on line 76
Edit    Delete  Last Name   First Name  Date Registered

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kyle_Site\Programming Rite\controle\view_users.php on line 89

```
<?php # Script 10.5 - #5
// This script retrieves all the records from the users table.
// This new version allows the results to be sorted in different ways.

$page_title = 'View the Current Users';
include ('header.html');
echo '<h1>Registered Users</h1>';



// Number of records to show per page:
$display = 5;

   // Determine how many pages there are...
if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])) { // Already been determined.
    $pages = $_GET['p'];
} else { // Need to determine.
    // Count the number of records:
     $q = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `kb2360716_entity_users`";
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $records = $row[0];
    // Calculate the number of pages...
    if ($records > $display) { // More than 1 page.
        $pages = ceil ($records/$display);
    } else {
        $pages = 1;
     }
} // End of p IF.

// Determine where in the database to start returning results...
if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s'])) {
    $start = $_GET['s'];
 } else {
$start = 0;
}

// Determine the sort...
// Default is by registration date.
$sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'rd';

// Determine the sorting order:
switch ($sort) {
    case 'ln':
         $order_by = 'last_name ASC';
         break;
    case 'fn':
        $order_by = 'first_name ASC';
        break;
    case 'rd':
        $order_by = 'registration_date ASC';
        break;
    default:
        $order_by = 'registration_date ASC';
        $sort = 'rd';
        break;
}

// Define the query:"SELECT last_name, first_name, DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, '%M        %d, %Y') AS dr, user_id FROM `kb2360716_entity_users` ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start,   $display";        
$q = "SELECT `id`,`username`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`email` FROM `kb2360716_entity_users` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

// Table header:
echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="75%">
<tr>
    <td align="left"><b>Edit</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>Delete</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b><a href="view_users.php?sort=ln">Last Name</a></b></td>
    <td align="left"><b><a href="view_users.php?sort=fn">First Name</a></b></td>
    <td align="left"><b><a href="view_users.php?sort=rd">Date Registered</a></b>  </td>
</tr>
';

// Fetch and print all the records....
$bg = '#eeeeee'; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee');
         echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
         <td align="left"><a href="edit_user.php?id=' . $row['user_id'] .   '">Edit</a></td>
        <td align="left"><a href="delete_user.php?id=' . $row['user_id'] . '">Delete</a></td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['last_name'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['dr'] . '</td>
    </tr>
    ';
 } // End of WHILE loop.

echo '</table>';
mysqli_free_result ($r);
mysqli_close($dbc);

// Make the links to other pages, if necessary.
if ($pages > 1) {

     echo '<br /><p>';
     $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

     // If it's not the first page, make a Previous button:
     if ($current_page != 1) {
        echo '<a href="view_users.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Previous</a> ';
    }

    // Make all the numbered pages:
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<a href="view_users.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
        } else {
            echo $i . ' ';
         }
    } // End of FOR loop.

    // If it's not the last page, make a Next button:
    if ($current_page != $pages) {
            echo '<a href="view_users.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Next</a>';
    }

     echo '</p>'; // Close the paragraph.

} // End of links section.
echo mysqli_error();
include ('footer.html');
?>
```

this is the top of my header.html:

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';
require 'core.inc.php';
if (!loggedin()) 
    {
        header("Location: index2.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

This is my connect.inc.php:

```
<?php
$mysql_host='209.129.8.3';
$mysql_user='47278';

$conn_error='Could not connect';
$mysql_db='47278';

$dbc = @mysqli_connect ($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
if(!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) || !@mysql_select_db($mysql_db)){
die($conn_error);
}

?>
```

I made the changes and got rid of 3 @'s and now I have a new error along with the two olds 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kyle_Site\Programming Rite\controle\view_users.php on line 21

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kyle_Site\Programming Rite\controle\view_users.php on line 76

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kyle_Site\Programming Rite\controle\view_users.php on line 89

Comment: Remove the "@" on line 61, and see if you get any errors.

Comment: There wasn't any change =\

Comment: Also, I don't see where you are defining your database connection `$dbc`

Comment: remove all of the @ signs infront of the mySQL calls. They hide errors that mySQL produce and probably there is the problem. Also, remove from your comments you passwords, we shouldn't know them :))

Comment: Use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see the error.

Comment: Now, with the 3 @'s removed and the new echo mysqli_error(); in the code i have 3 errors and now this one Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kyle_Site\Programming Rite\controle\view_users.php on line 120

Answer (score -1):

the problem is here:

```
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
```

remve the @ infront of it and you will see the mySQL error that gives you. This way you suppressed the error and it results as FALSE, which is why the next lines fails after.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It is not polite to berate someone for not submitting their answer in the correct format, when they are trying to help, and your comment is off topic. Your comment has nothing to do with my question.